# Syncing Calendar with phone

Tags: linux-mint, synchronization, privacy, calendar

I'm well aware, that similar questions exist, but due to my lack of expertise the respective answers couldn't help me make it work.

So I've just recently transitioned from Windows to LinuxMint (my first use of Linux) and have grown more aware of data protection and privacy.

So now, I've used Google Calendar all the time, because of it's simplicity, functionality and availability on Windows(for my PC), Android(phone) and iOS(Tablet), but because of the reasons I already mentioned, I'd like to abandon Google Services as much as possible and am now looking for a Calendar Software for LinuxMint, that provides different coloured entries, reoccuring meetings and can be synchronized to both iOS and Android.

As mentioned, there are similar threads out there, but I feel like all the answers expect some basic knowledge I do not yet possess, so
I would be really gladful for your help!

Best regards,
Seb

Answer (score 0):

Running a solution on your local Mint install is probably not what you want, unless you are going to sync your other devices to it locally.

Instead, find a provider that you can use, that supports sync, that has the privacy you want.  Once such would be ProtonMail.  Another might be FastMail.  And there are others.